# compile error on compile Livermore Loops coded in C

Tags: parallel-processing, openmp

I want to compile and run Livermore Loops in C code
But every time I get compile error and I don't get any clear answer
This is a source code page
https://netlib.org/benchmark/livermorec
Can anyone help me with this?
I want to compile livermore loops in c and parallelize it using openmp library. Unfortunately, at the first stage, I cannot compile and run the codes related to the livermore loops
I am new to c tools and parallize
I've applied everything I've learned about c, unfortunately it doesn't work for me to compile and run those loops.

Comment: What kind of help do you imagine? The one provided here is by answering questions, but you have not really asked one. Share some details, specifics, an error message would be good.

Answer (score 0):

The Livermore Loops are ancient. Leaving aside the question of how relevant they are, they are coded in pre-Ansi C. So you need to give your compiler an option to accept this prehistoric syntax.

There is some information here: https://www.reddit.com/r/C_Programming/comments/3gwr4j/resources_for_preansi_c/